# What is the difference between "I will need something" and "I will be needing something"?

Tags: future-tense

Is there any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> Don't throw your boots away yet because you **will need** them.
>
> Don't throw your boots away yet because you **will be needing** them.

I cannot feel any difference. But I am sure there is some because why would anyone say *I will be needing*  when *I will need* is shorter.

Comment: Every time I have seen the form *"will be needing"*, it is used to say that something will be needed very soon (i.e., a specific occasion is mentioned or suggested). On the other hand, *"will need"* can be said if something will be of use after 40 years or very soon. Of course, that is a very limited observation and there may be more reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it by changing the verb and the context.

> Don't put your boots away yet because you will wash them.
>
> Don't put your boots away yet because you will be washing them.

This makes it a bit more clearer I feel, as the first sentence doesn't really make any sense.

Using the "be" form suggests a definite future event to come.

With regards to "need", I feel the "you will need them" form, implies, not a single future event, but a more general sense of needing them for the future. To me it feels like it represents a presumption (i.e. with no definite future event in mind), but one that is generally accepted as being reliable, at least in the mind of the person who says it; it's a "goes without saying" thing.

For example:

> You'll need them for the winter.

Sounds a lot more natural than:

> You'll be needing them for the winter.